# Plivo Speak doesn't work

Tags: plivo

I have created a really simple xml file for testing plivo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
   <Speak>Hello, Input your 4-digit pin number</Speak>
   <GetDigits action="https://example.com/voice/plivo/renderVoiceCallDirective/wGather" method="POST">
      <Speak>Enter your 4-digit pin number, followed by the hash key</Speak>
   </GetDigits>
   <Speak>Input not received. Thank you</Speak>
   <Redirect>/voice/plivo/timeoutRedirect/xxx</Redirect>
</Response>
```

In theory, plivo will read the content of  and gather the input digits
but it seems like the Speak and GetDigits doesn't work, because after getting this xml, plivo directly goes to the redirect url. The call will last several second and hangup. Any one know why this happens? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XML is validated first before executing it. The URL given in "Redirect" tag is not a valid URL. So the XML fails the validation and the call hangs up.
Try using a valid URL in Redirect XML.